# ajax call on angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to validate a number input using angularjs.
The page works as desired by itself, however it does not work when I call the page with ajax.
Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Working angularjs jlgtest3.jsp ...

```
<div ng-app="total">
<script>
angular.module('total', [])
.controller('totalController', ['$scope', function($scope) { }]);
</script>

<form name="totalForm" ng-controller="totalController">
<input name="totalHours" ng-model="total" type="number" value="" />
<p ng-show="totalForm.totalHours.$error.number">Not valid number!</p>
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

Not working with ajax call (jlgtest4.jsp calling jlgtest3.jsp)...

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
function newajax() {
var xRequest1;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xRequest1=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xRequest1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xRequest1.onreadystatechange=function ()
    {
        if((xRequest1.readyState==4) && (xRequest1.status==200))
        {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xRequest1.responseText;
        }
    }
    var urlencode = "jlgtest3.jsp";

    xRequest1.open("post",urlencode,true);
    xRequest1.send();   
}
</script>
</head>

<input type="button" onclick="newajax()" value="button" />
<div id="test">

</div>
</html>
```

I attempted the angular ajax call as some people suggested, but I couldnt get it to work...

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="total">
<script>
angular.module('total', [])
.controller('totalController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $http.POST("jlgtest3.jsp").then(function(response) {
        $scope.test = response.data;
    });
 }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="totalController">
<input type="button" value="button" />
{{test}}
</div>

</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Using the updated code check the console for any errors and double check the network panel to validate that the AJAX request has been made and the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question again, but a little bit more simplified and Moncef Hassein-bey was able to answer my question [Use Ajax to put external angularjs element in html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574314/use-ajax-to-put-external-angularjs-element-in-html-page)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) { }]);
</script>
<script>

function newajax() {
var xRequest1;
    xRequest1=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xRequest1.onreadystatechange=function ()
    {
        if((xRequest1.readyState==4) && (xRequest1.status==200))
        {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xRequest1.responseText;
            angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('test'), ['myApp']);
        }
    }
    xRequest1.open("post","jlgtest.html",true);
    xRequest1.send();   
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="button" onClick="newajax()" />
    <div id="test">

    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Basically I needed to add the angular.bootstrap line of code, and the angular.module(... script needed to be in my main page

this is the called page code...

```
<html>  
<div ng-app="myApp">
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="myController">
    <input name="numberField" ng-model="myModel" type="number" value="" />
    <p ng-show="myForm.numberField.$error.number">Not valid number!</p>
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular, you should consider using the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or even the [$resource service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). These both abstract ajax requests into a much simpler form. So instead of

```
xRequest1.open("post",urlencode,true);
xRequest1.send();

...etc...
```

You might have something like:

```
$http.POST(urlencode).then(function(response) {

  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=response.data;
  // do other stuff with the response
});
```

And that will encapsulate essentially your entire `newajax` function.

As for @messerbill 's answer, you should not be making $http calls in your controller. These are better utilized within a service or factory that you then inject into your controller. Controllers are for business logic and should not deal with fetching and sending data.

Answer (score 0):

you also can use a standart Ajax call but better use the $http angular way. You should call it inside of your angular controller.

`XMLHttpRequest` is an object used by Ajax - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

**updated answer**

Why dont you use Angular in the way its meant to be used? You should send your post inside of you angular service or controller. Don't manipulate your DOM if you use AngularJS like you did here:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=response.data;
```

istead you should do it that way:

```
angular.module('total', [])
.controller('totalController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $http.POST("yourURL").then(function(response) {
        $scope.test = response.data;
    });
 }]);
 //template
<input type="button" value="button" />
<div ng-controller="totalController">
  {{test}}
</div>
</html>
```

I have not tested it yet, but it should work - next time create a fiddle ;)

Comment: I tried your block of code, it didnt work. {{test}} shows up as {{test}} instead of rendering. I tried to make a fiddle but I dont think you can with ajax since you have 2 pages your dealing with. Sorry Im a newb, if you can make a fiddle with your code I would appreciate it @messerbill