# Use Ajax to put external angularjs element in html page

Tags: html, ajax, angularjs

I have a very simple form using angularjs that validates a number field test.html ...

http://plnkr.co/edit/mfxdTxGUXLZswzl1nyF2?p=preview

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) { }]);
</script>

<form name="myForm" ng-controller="myController">
    <input name="numberField" ng-model="myModel" type="number" value="" />
    <p ng-show="myForm.numberField.$error.number">Not valid number!</p>
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

I want to put that form into a different html page...

```
<html>
<div id="test">
<!--I want my angular js number element to go here-->
</div>
</html>
```

Normally when I do something like this I use javascript and make a request to the page and use innerhtml to place the form where i want it, something like this...

```
<script>
var xRequest1;
    xRequest1=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xRequest1.onreadystatechange=function ()
    {
        if((xRequest1.readyState==4) && (xRequest1.status==200))
        {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xRequest1.responseText;
        }
    }
    xRequest1.open("post","test.html",true);
    xRequest1.send();
</script>
```

However this is not working, any idea how I can do this? or is this even possible? Ive never worked with angularjs before. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could use ng-include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you are building angular app from scratch then, you should
  consider, putting ng-app in the main index and using ng-include as
  @Ronnie pointed out.
- But, If you are forced to integrate angular, in one place on legacy
  code, you can manually bootstrap angular app, after, filling the
  div#test in the ajax callback using [angular.boostrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)  :

[Here is a working demo using your exemple.](http://plnkr.co/edit/SX2Hsd9t06A7MVrRxvvF?p=preview)

```
var xRequest1;
    xRequest1=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xRequest1.onreadystatechange=function ()
    {
        if((xRequest1.readyState==4) && (xRequest1.status==200))
        {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xRequest1.responseText;
            // bootstrap your app here ...
            angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('test'), ['myApp']);
        }
    }
    xRequest1.open("get","test.html",true);
    xRequest1.send();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to make that work for way too long. Out of curiosity, why do I need to have the angular.module('myApp'... script in my main page? since all of that is in my page that a call to populate my test div. Its not the end of the world, but I couldnt make it work unless i had it in the main page.